# How to include sub element as a part of word query in MarkLogic

Tags: xml, search, xquery, marklogic

We have data in xml as follows

```
<person>
    <snm>Joisar</snm>
    <fnm>Manish</fnm>
    <init>Mr.</init>
</person>
```

Word query is as follows

```
<options>
    <word>
        <element ns="" name="{$constants:surname}"/>
        <element ns="" name="{$constants:foreName}"/>
        <element ns="" name="{$constants:initial}"/>
        <element ns="" name="{$constants:prefix}"/>
        <element ns="" name="{$constants:suffix}"/>
        <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>diacritic-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>whitespace-insensitive</term-option>
    </word>
</options>
```

When we search for First Name OR Last name, it works fine & we get results

```
search:search($SearchWord, $SearchOption, $Start, $pageLength)
```

Now when user wants to search for full name i.e. "Joisar Manish", it does not show the results, as both are in separate elements. At least one way it should search i.e. Joisar Manish OR Manish Joisar

Can you please help me with how to write word query to make sure it works as expected ? or we need to go with different approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two basic approaches here:

1. Is to search for each part of the name separately and `AND` them together, logically `Joisar AND Manish`.
2. The way you are thinking about it, as a phrase search. Here, however, you need to do some reconfiguration of the database, because by default phrases break at element boundaries. So you want to declare these low level elements as `phrase-through` elements. Then you do your search to the `person` element. That assumes the pieces are actually adjacent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, "phrase-through" element worked and it's working as expected. Thanks a lot.